# Hibernate could not locate .cfg file eventhough it's in the source main

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, hibernate.cfg.xml

I am using Intellij.
Here is how the project structure looks like.

[image: Project Structure]

Here is how the DBConnect class looks like.

[image: DBConnect]

I am getting the following error: **Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]**

The **src** folder has added Hibernate framework support, the Hibernate plugin is enabled and the following lines are added to my **build.gradle** file:

```
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.6'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: '5.2.14.Final'
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
```

**NB!** I have tried removing the .cfg file from the resources folder to the src root folder, but with no luck.

Comment: Try to add "/" before path ("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml")

Comment: That didn't help. It seems that the problem is with the Java 9.